# is constant sheaf perverse on a Cohen-Macaulay variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves

Let $X$ be a connected Cohen-Macaulay algebraic variety of dimension $d$, say, over $\mathbb C$. Is it true that $\underline{{\mathbb C}_X}[d]$ is a perverse sheaf, where $\underline{{\mathbb C}_X}$ is the constant sheaf on $X({\mathbb C})$? This is true if $X$ is a set-theoretic complete intersection by a theorem of Le Dung Trang.

Comment: I think this fails in general. Take the cone $C$ over a smooth projective pair $(X,L)$ with  $H^i(X,L^j) = 0$ for $0 < i < d = \dim(X)$ and all $j$, so $C$ is CM. Deligne's formula for the IC-sheaf says $IC_C = \tau^{\leq -1} (j_* \mathbf{C}[d+1])$ is perverse, where $j:C-\{0\} \subset C$. The cone of the map $\mathbf{C}[d+1] \to IC_C$  is then a bunch of skyscraper sheaves supported in a whole range of degrees if $X$ is interesting (as $C-0$ is homotopic to an $S^1$-bundle over $X$ attached to $L$). So I think $\mathbf{C}[d+1]$ is not perverse. I can try to write an explicit example later.

Comment: I agree, I think $X$ being an abelian variety provides a counterexample: the cone is the skyscraper tensored with the primitive part of $H^*(X)$ which in the abelian variety category will be nonzero in every possible degree.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that does not quite work because it's not CM: the $\mathcal{O}$-cohomology of the abelian variety causes the cone to not be CM. But you can replace the abelian variety with the blowup of projective space along an abelian variety to reproduce the same phenomenon.

Comment: ah, that's right, we need $X$ with $H^i(X,O)=0$ for $i>0$ but with some primitive cohomology, your example appears to do the job. Thanks!